Why doe EF Core 6 validate Count(*) against null?
I have the following simple query:
var students = from s in dbContext.Students
               select new 
                      {
                          Name = s.Name,
                          HasGrades = s.Grades.Where(x => x.IsActive).Count() == 1
                      };

Column HasGrades is boolean and must show true only if exactly one active grade exists for student.
I am bit puzzled why EF Core translates it into two subqueries and additionally checks COUNT(*) result against null? Postgres COUNT(*) never returns null:
SELECT 
    s."NAME" AS "Name", 
    ((SELECT COUNT(*)::INT
      FROM "GRADES" AS p0
      WHERE (s."NAME" = p0."NAME") AND p0."IS_ACTIVE") = 1) 
        AND (((SELECT COUNT(*)::INT
               FROM "GRADES" AS p0
               WHERE (s."NAME" = p0."NAME") AND p0."IS_ACTIVE") IS NOT NULL)) AS "HasGrades"
FROM 
    "STUDENTS" AS s

UPDATE:
If I change this line
HasGrades = s.Grades.Where(x => x.IsActive).Count() == 1

to this:
HasGrades = s.Grades.Where(x => x.IsActive).Count() == 1 ? true : false

then it's translated to
 CASE
    WHEN (
        SELECT COUNT(*)::INT
        FROM "GRADES" AS p1
        WHERE (p."NAME" = p1."NAME") AND p1."IS_ACTIVE") = 1 THEN TRUE
    ELSE FALSE
END

and looks like it's a better result

? true : false should be completely redundant.  If you're satisfied with that,. make sure you leave a detailed comment as to why it's there because it otherwise should be perfectly valid to remove that part of the expression and someone is going to want to remove it.

@madreflection I am not satisfied this but it's only way to force ef core translates it to single COUNT subquery.

Hey. I don't blame you.

EF Core itself isn't producing this SQL--it's the query provider that EF Core is configured to use (I'm guessing Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL).
Writing a LINQ query provider is hard. Developers will typically set their priorities in this order:

Make the generated SQL correct
Make the generated SQL fast
Make the generated SQL readable

Since complex code leads to more bugs, they will often make choices that make their code simpler, even if it makes the generated SQL more complex. I'm guessing this is one of those cases.
COUNT(*) won't return NULL, but all the other aggregate functions will. It's likely the query provider developers figured they could keep their code simpler and less error-prone by treating all aggregate functions similarly. PostgreSQL's query engine might recognize that COUNT(*) can't produce null, and produce the same query plan anyway.

Nitpick: Npgsql is an ADO.NET provider. Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL is the LINQ query provider for EF Core.

Also, one of that package's owners (and biggest contributors, I'm sure) is one of the EF Core developers, so the "it's hard" argument is quite relative since he knows how EF Core works inside and out.

@madreflection Thanks for the feedback. I updated the answer to accommodate your nitpick. :-)  I think "it's hard" applies regardless of who's doing it. Most people have a hard enough time writing complex queries in any language. Writing software that translates queries from one language into another is a whole new level. I'm in awe of the developers behind any of the LINQ query providers.
